# Движение по точкам

Tags: алгоритм, javascript, html5

Имеется канвас (html5), имеется точка с координатами (x, y), имеется массив точек пути с координатами `(mPathX[i], mPathY[i])`.

Необходимо запустить первую точку по координатам пути. То есть чтобы начальная точка двигалась от `(mPathX[0], mPathY[0]) -> (mPathX[1], mPathY[1]) -> .. -> (mPathX[i], mPathY[i])`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, алгоритм.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно достраивать прямоугольник между точками, а точки - это противоположные вершины диагонали.

[image: http://upyourpic.org/images/201211/j52clnpmo8.png]

Выходит зависимость:

```
f = x/y 
y(x) = n/f
x(y) = n*f
```

Т.е. мы можем знать координату и на абсциссе и на ординате.

Если же вам нужно движение по параболе, то тут чуть сложнее.

Answer (score 0):

Прочитайте про [кривые Безье](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%8C%D0%B5), они как раз неплохо подходят для этой задачи.